# Writing sum over loop using math.factorial within

Tags: python-3.x, sum

I'm trying to write a function to calculate such a sum:

```
∑_(k=0)^n 1/k!
```

So expected result with n = 2:
1/factorial(0) + 1/factorial(1) + 1/factorial(2) = 1 + 1 + 0.5 + 2.5

I have tried this but it isn't working. I can't figure out why. I have thought of trying to save quotients as a list then summing over it but it does not seem an efficient way.

```
import math 
def test_fun(n:int)->int:
    Sn = 0
    k:int
    for k in range(0,n,1):
        Sn += 1/math.factorial(k)
        return(Sn)

test_fun(2)
Out[75]: 1.0
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
unindented return(Sn) as per Carcigenicate's suggestion.
Also figured that range(0,2) returns 0,1 and not 0,1,2. All good now!

```
def test_fun(x:int)->int:
    n = x+1
    Sn = 0
    for k in range(0,n,1):
        Sn = Sn + 1/math.factorial(k)
    return(Sn)

test_fun(2)
```

Comment: `return(Sn)` shouldn't be inside the loop. Unindent it. I don't know if that's the only issue, but that'll definitely cause problems.

Comment: That got me closer, thanks! The function returns 2.0 instead of 2.5 now though. I'll add the edit.

Comment: Yeah the copy/paste from word didn't work too well, but it's supposed to be N on top of the Sigma to say that the sum goes over values of k from 0 to n.